# How to make simplier this code?

Tags: c#, uwp

```
if (spanList.Count(p => p.ClassName == "p") == 2 && (spanList.Count(p => p.ClassName == "s") == 2))
{
    lesson.lesson2Name = spanList.Where(p => p.ClassName == "p").ToList()[1].TextContent;
    lesson.lesson2Place = spanList.Where(p => p.ClassName == "s").ToList()[1].TextContent;
    lesson.lesson2Tag = adressList.Where(p => p.ClassName == "n").ToList()[1].TextContent;
    lesson.lesson2TagHref = adressList[1].GetAttribute("href");
}
else if (spanList.Count(p => p.ClassName == "p") == 4 && (spanList.Count(p => p.ClassName == "s") == 2))
{
    lesson.lesson2Name = spanList.Where(p => p.ClassName == "p").ToList()[2].TextContent;
    lesson.lesson2Place = spanList.Where(p => p.ClassName == "s").ToList()[1].TextContent;
    lesson.lesson2Tag = spanList.Where(p => p.ClassName == "p").ToList()[3].TextContent;
    lesson.lesson2TagHref = "";
}
```

Only index in list is changing. How can i make this simplier?

Comment: you can do this much easier with a switch case statement then checking if ClassName ==`p` || ClassName ==`s` if you do not understand the code you have then break it down to more simpler steps. also explain more in detail what the problem and or issue is besides just saying only inside list is changing

Comment: thanks for suggest, check code at bottom

Answer (score 1):

That looks pretty bad from a performance and readability point of view, since you are iterating through the entire list every time you want to know something about it.

You should try something like

```
List<YourObject> pList = spanList.Where(p => p.ClassName == "p").ToList();
List<YourObject> sList = spanList.Where(p => p.ClassName == "s").ToList();
if (pList.Count == 2 && sList.Count == 2)
{
    lesson.lesson2Name = pList[1].TextContent;
    lesson.lesson2Place = sList[1].TextContent;
    lesson.lesson2Tag = adressList.Where(p => p.ClassName == "n").ToList()[1].TextContent;
    lesson.lesson2TagHref = adressList[1].GetAttribute("href");
}
else if (pList.Count == 4 && sList.Count == 2))
{
    lesson.lesson2Name = pList[2].TextContent;
    lesson.lesson2Place = sList[1].TextContent;
    lesson.lesson2Tag = pList.ToList()[3].TextContent;
    lesson.lesson2TagHref = "";
}
```

Comment: And to think that i could not came up on this.
Thanks a lot, i dont know how did i miss it.
Also, 're u sure we cant simplier it more?

Comment: check an answer at bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
var pList = spanList.Where(p => p.ClassName == "p").ToList();
var sList = spanList.Where(p => p.ClassName == "s").ToList();

if(sList.Count == 2)
{
    string name = "";
    string tag = "";
    string taghref = "";

    switch(pList.Count)
    {
        case 2:
            name = pList[1].TextContent;
            tag = adressList.Where(p => p.ClassName == "n").ToList()[1].TextContent;
            taghref = adressList[1].GetAttribute("href");
            break;
        case 4:
            name = pList[2].TextContent;
            tag = pList[3].TextContent;
            break;
        default:
            name = "error";
            break;
    }

    lesson.lesson2Name = name;
    lesson.lesson2Place = sList[1].TextContext;
    lesson.lesson2Tag = tag;
    lesson.lesson2TagHref = taghref;
}
```

@Crusha K. Rool i used a switch statement as MethodMan told, and get this. Can it be done better?

Comment: why are you posting this as an answer when you should update your original question with this posting..?

Comment: I am usually not a fan of useless assignments if they can be avoided. I'd just put the declaration `string name;` up there, without the `= "";` part. Every case in your switch statement will assign a value to `name`, so that original assignment will never be used. You can do the same for the other variables by simply adding the default assignment as part of the respective cases instead of doing it prematurely. But in the end it boils down to personal preference.

Comment: @MethodMan sorry for no-ogar from my site, i am doing first steps on stackoverflow. I will remember this.

Thanks for your reply. I will be coding like you said.